# Target recv() on same socket through different threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, networking

My question is simple and might have been asked several times. But somehow I am unable to find it. Now brain starting to hurt in search of the answer, So please help.

I have 1 process running on socket x and it has 2 threads. Now both threads have there separate task and on recv() of a command to the socket I want certain command to be received by certain thread only.
Like command A, B, C belongs to thread 1 and D, E belongs to thread 2. So When command A is triggered it should go to thread 1 only.

But currently when I am hitting certain command I it going to either of thread on random.
So my questions are:

1. What determine that certain recv will get the message. If My both recv statements are sitting ideal then which one will be picked and on which condition.
2. I know socket.send() is not thread safe but can I somehow add identifier to my recv() and while send() only send to particular recv().

Note: I know I can use a custom handler for this and divert the message according to need. But this ques is more for understanding purpose.

Comment: "I want certain command to be received by certain thread only": in general this is neither possible nor desirable. You should have one thread reading from the socket and despatching the requests to wherever they should go.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. @user207421. You said it not desirable. Is there any disadvantage to that flow (assuming if it was possible) or would it have been a security risk and why/how?

Comment: You can't assume it's possible. It isn't. You can't assume anything about what comes out of a `recv()` call.

Answer (score 0):

> What determine that certain recv will get the message. If My both recv
> statements are sitting ideal then which one will be picked and on
> which condition.

If multiple threads are waiting in `recv()` on the same socket, it's indeterminate/unpredictable which one will receive any particular byte of data.  For UDP sockets, that might be acceptable, since each UDP packet is self-contained, but for TCP (and other stream-based-sockets) this is generally unworkable, since it's likely that e.g. thread A will get half of the bytes that were sent for a given transaction, and thread B will get the other half, so neither thread will receive the entire set of bytes that are necessary to do something useful.

> I know socket.send() is not thread safe but can I somehow add
> identifier to my recv() and while send() only send to particular
> recv().

The way to do this is either to use two different sockets (and two different connections, if you're using a connection-based protocol), or to have a single thread dedicated to network I/O that does all the `recv()`-ing, and passed the received messages on to the appropriate other threads.